# F# timers confusion: there seems to be several options, how to use it?

Tags: timer, f#

I have the following in C#:

```
var timer = new Timer(x => { task.Invoke(); }, state, startDelay, interval);
```

I'm trying to do the same in F# and from what I see online, there is a timer in *System.Threading* but there is also a timer in *System.Timers* and .. they're both called Timer.

This won't compile:

```
let timer = new Timer
                (
                    fun x -> (printfn "hello"),
                    new Object(),
                    1000,
                    5000
                )
```

I've established that the one in System.Threading is the one needed, but I don't understand what is wrong.

There error is:

> Program.fs(21, 34): [FS0001] This expression was expected to have type    'unit'    but here has type    ''a * 'b * 'c * 'd'

The decompiler shows this:

> ```
> public Timer(TimerCallback callback, [Nullable(2)] object state, int dueTime, int period)
>   : this(callback, state, dueTime, period, true)
> {
> }
> ```

I don't understand the error at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. The problem you're running into (and it's a common one) is that C# supports implicit conversion from the lambda (`x => { task.Invoke(); }`) into an instance of the `TimerCallback` delegate type. F# does not support implicit conversion as a rule.  If you create an instance of the `TimerCallback` delegate yourself, you can see it all works fine:

```
open System.Threading

let timer = new Timer(
          TimerCallback (fun _ -> printfn "hello"),
          null,
          1000,
          5000
        )
```

Comment: How does the compiler reach the error: This expression was expected to have type 'unit' but here has type ''a * 'b * 'c * 'd' ?

Comment: my guess is that, due to the lack of parens around your function lambda `fun x -> printfn "Hello"`, the compiler interpreted the entire set of constructor parameters you passed as a single argument: a function that took something and returned a tuple of 4 elements